# Riak admin and dataviewer

Tags: user-interface, riak

Are there any actively developed UIs and Tools to view data stored in a riak database? The only tools that I'm currently able to find are:

- ngRiakAdmin: last commit 9 monts ago, not really functioning e.g. for a riak behind a reverse proxy
- Briak: requires ruby and fails on this requirement on ubuntu 12.04
- Java riak-admin: inactive

My use cases are to have a UI which will allow me to get a generic view on the buckets and data stored in riak. Doesn't need to be anything fancy. I don't need a UI to change riak parameters or to administer it.

Answer (score 0):

We've installed Rekon in Riak, pretty handy, works in browser. So if you are running a terminal, you can check whatever in Riak via browser of your choice. Not suitable for large db's